# Convert INT to STRING/TEXT SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I wan to convert data in table SQL from int to string or text. I have code to convert it but it does not work.

The data still be int not convert to sting/text

My code

```
DECLARE @U0 int
SET @U0=1905152

SELECT CAST(@U0 as varchar(10))
```

[screenshot](http://prntscr.com/8csfd2) of the output

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Output is converted to varchar. What exactly is the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

The type of your select is a varchar. Here is the proof.

```
USE TEMPDB

DECLARE @U0 int
SET @U0=1905152

SELECT test = CAST(@U0 as varchar(8))
into #temp

SELECT c.name, [type] = t.name, c.max_length, c.[precision], c.scale
  FROM sys.columns AS c
  INNER JOIN sys.types AS t
  ON c.system_type_id = t.system_type_id
  AND c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
  WHERE c.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp');
```

Result :

```
name type    max_length precision scale
---- ------- ---------- --------- -----
test varchar 8          0         0
```